# Passing arg to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, exec, call, sys

I have a series of scripts that get called in an explicit order by another `run.py`.

Inside `run.py` I have the following:

```
script1 = str(sys.path[0]) + "\\script1.py"
subprocess.call(["Python", script1])
```

And so on for 3 scripts. If I would like to pass two arguments to script 1 in this format, arguments such as explicit run settings to be used in the script when it is executing, how would I do this? I have a feeling it would rely on sys.argv within script1, but have gotten errors about the argument being out of range regardless of what index position I pass.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subprocesses takes a list of arguments, which it then turns into a command it executes.

So:

```
subprocess.call(["Python", script1, 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```

To `subprocess.call`, *all* the parts of its list are arguments. You just happen to be specifying "Python" and script1, but to subprocess, both are just other arguments.

There is a lot more reading on the [documentation for subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) which I would recommend looking over.

Comment: So then within `script1.py` I would utilize those arguments as sys.argv[2] and sys.argv[3] ?

Comment: @Alt182 that ends up effectively as a command `python \\script1.py arg1 arg2.` You need to process them accordingly.